# RESTEASY -Spring Exception mapper for javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException is not getting Involed

Tags: spring, resteasy

Hi I am using Reasteasy 3 along spring 3.
I have defined multiple Exception mappers for my project, and most of them are getting invoked whenever concerned Exceptions are raised.
**But I am facing problem with **“javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException”** when this exception is raised its handler is not getting invoked.**
All Exception mappers including mapper for “NotFoundException” exception are defined/configured in same manner and they are getting invoked except mapper for NotFoundException.

Is there any different way to configure Exception mappers for JAX-RS exception ..please help I am stuck here .

```
code for Exception mappers
package com.xyz.exception;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CCDBNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {       
          // Logs and code          
        }
}
```

other Exception mapper configured and defined in a Excatly similar way are getting Invoked  ... see snap shot for working Exception mapper

```
package com.xyz.exception;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException;

@Provider
public class CCDBJAXBUnmarshalExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JAXBUnmarshalException> {
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {       
          // Logs and code          
        }
}

package com.xyz.exception;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CCDBApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CCDBApplicationException>{
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {       
          // Logs and code          
        }
}
```

Spring Configuration for provider annotation

```
 <!-- Auto Reegistry of RESTEasy providers -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider"/>
   </context:component-scan>
```

Comment: This should work. Two guesses: The `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException` is wrapped by another exception or there's another ExceptionMapper in your classpath which handles the `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but Exception mappers for any **"javax.ws.rs.*"**  exceptions are not getting invokes although they are getting registered .

to overcome this problem i have used servlet filter  ... i posting my code to help others whoever is facing same issues

Register below filter in your web.xml file.

**filter code :**

```
public class CCDBExceptionFilter implements Filter {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CCDBExceptionFilter.class);
    private static final String NOTFOUND_MESSAGE =  "{\"ErrorResponse\":{\"errorCode\":1,\"errorMessage\":\"Invalid request, There is no service configured to handle provided request\"}}";
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("CCDBExceptionFilter got initiated" );
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain filterChain)throws IOException, ServletException {            
        HttpServletResponse res =  (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req =  (HttpServletRequest) request;     
        logger.debug("Request recived to process " + req.getPathInfo());        
        DummyResponse dummyResponse = new DummyResponse((HttpServletResponse)response);  
        filterChain.doFilter(request, dummyResponse);                
        logger.debug("Request handled for  " + req.getPathInfo());              
        if(404 == dummyResponse.getErrorcode()){
            logger.debug("Found 404 error code" );
            res.setStatus(400);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
            out.println(NOTFOUND_MESSAGE);            
            out.close();             
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

**Dummy Response class**

```
public class DummyResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DummyResponse.class);

    private CharArrayWriter buffer; // This can be used as an Writer
    int errorcode;

    public int getErrorcode() {
        return errorcode;
    }

    public void setErrorcode(int errorcode) {
        this.errorcode = errorcode;
    }

    public DummyResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        buffer = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(buffer);
    }

    public void setStatus(int sc) {
        if (404 == sc) {
            setErrorcode(404);
            super.setStatus(400);
        } else {
            super.setStatus(sc);
        }

    }

    public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
        if (404 == sc) {
            setErrorcode(404);
            super.setStatus(400);
        } else {
            super.setStatus(sc);
        }
    }

    public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
        if (404 == sc) {
            setErrorcode(404);
            super.setStatus(400);
        } else {
            super.setStatus(sc);
        }

    }

}
```